# DOM sanitize function is not escaping the text that user entered

Tags: javascript, angular

Was trying to use Angular Sanitize API with the user input entered by the user inside angular form.
But the Angular's `Sanitize()` is not escaping the input entered.

**.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  userName = 'Angular';

  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  onSave(): void {
    console.log('save clicked api call');
    this.sanitizeUserName();
  }

  sanitizeUserName(): string {
    const domSanitize = this.domSanitizer.sanitize(1, this.userName);
    console.log('sanitized text/html', domSanitize);
    return domSanitize;
  }
}
```

**.html**

```
<form #userForm="ngForm">
  <label>Username: </label>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="userName" name="username" />

  <div>
    <span>View : </span>
    <div [innerHTML]="userName"></div>
  </div>

  <br />
  <br />
  <button type="button" (click)="onSave()">Save</button>
</form>
```

Please find the live example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kidre6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts). In `component.ts` I have added few examples to verify if the input sanitization.

If someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

sanitize method models is:

```
 sanitize(context: SecurityContext, value: SafeValue | string | null): string | null;
```

and the SecurityContext model is:

```
enum SecurityContext {
    NONE = 0,
    HTML = 1,
    STYLE = 2,
    SCRIPT = 3,
    URL = 4,
    RESOURCE_URL = 5
}
```

So it seems that you should use the number one for SecurityContext

```
  sanitizeUserName(): string {
    const domSanitize = this.domSanitizer.sanitize(1, this.userName);
    console.log('sanitized text/html', domSanitize);
    return domSanitize;
  }
```

Comment: I have used 1 already but that is not sanitizing with 1 as well